# Configuring spring-boot-starter-remote-shell using profiles

Tags: shell, spring-boot

I'm having some trouble configuring spring-boot-starter-remote-shell using profiles. The short of it is that I would like to set up different ports/useranmes/etc for each profile my application uses.

I see the ShellProperties bean, but that looks like it's pulling configuration settings from application.properties, which I would also like to avoid.

Is this even possible? I can't find references on how to set the shell properties outside of application.properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to create `@Beans` of type `ShellProperties` ([source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/ShellProperties.java)) in each profile.

Why don't you like ‘application.properties` (it's what everybody does even when they aren't using Spring Boot)?

Comment: I'm in the process of porting an application that had a custom configuration file over to a YAML file, and don't necessarily want everything pulled into the Spring environment yet. Also want to avoid spreading configuration across multiple files.  
  I guess one thing we could do is use application.yml and split it up by profiles - I assume application.yml support multiple documents inside the file?